# multiplying and dividing from user input in c#

Tags: c#

So this is the question.......

Context for code:

The longer you shower, the more water you use. But just how much? Even if you have a "low-flow" showerhead, odds are your shower spits out 1.5 gallons of water per minute. A gallon is 128 ounces, and so that shower spits out 1.5 × 128 = 192 ounces of water per minute. A typical bottle of water might be 16 ounces. So taking a 1-minute shower is akin to using 192 ÷ 16 = 12 bottles of water. Taking a 10-minute shower is like using 120 bottles of water. These numbers help put into perspective the amount of water being spent in a shower! 
Write, in a file called water.c in your ~/workspace/pset1 directory, a program that prompts the user for the length of his or her shower in minutes (as a positive integer) and then prints the equivalent number of bottles of water (as an integer) per the sample output below, wherein underlined text represents some user’s input.

username@ide50:~/workspace/pset1 $ ./water
minutes: 10
bottles: 120
For simplicity, you may assume that the user will input a positive integer, so no need for error-checking (or any loops) this time! And no need to worry about overflow!

My current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace console_water
{
    class water_amount
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*variable decleration*/
            int multiply, divide;
            int userInput = Console.Read();
            multiply = 192;
            divide = 16;

            /*getting user input*/
            Console.WriteLine("Length of shower in minutes:");

            Console.Read();

            userInput = multiply / divide;

            Console.WriteLine("The amount of water used is:" + userInput);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: And another question using `Console.Read()` incorrectly.

Comment: Cool. What doesn't work though? What are you getting and what are you expecting? Seriously, think about the people who are here to help you. We don't read minds or something like that. Give us as much info as necessary, but no more (what's with that massive intro?).

Comment: This is very wrong. You get a *character code* before prompting the user, you then get another *character code* which is discarded, then you just divide two intergers with integer division.

Comment: If I am showering under a low flow shower head, I will shower for 3 straight hours to get the shampoo out of my hair that a normal shower would have washed out in seconds.

Comment: What if I use a bath?

Comment: just added some more detail im not sure how to get input from user then perform the multiply and division parts and then display output

Comment: anyone any suggestions or examples?

Comment: @AshPeterson Your update was just adding more of the question you were given, you didn't answer any of the questions async asked.

Comment: remove the blablabla, state what you have done and ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace console_water
{
    class water_amount
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*variable decleration*/
            int multiply, divide;
            int userInput;
            multiply = 192;
            divide = 16;

            /*getting user input*/
            Console.WriteLine("Length of shower in minutes:");

            userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int numBottlesMinute =  multiply / divide;

            Console.WriteLine("The amount of water used is:" + userInput * numBottlesMinute);
        }
    }
}
```

`userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` this reads your shower length

`int numBottlesMinute =  multiply / divide;` You should keep the number of bottles you use per liter in one variable(better constant ... but ok for your example)

`Console.WriteLine("The amount of water used is:" + userInput * numBottlesMinute);` Just print the result, number of bottles per minute * length of the shower.

Comment: thank you so much for the help i think it is now working. and apologies for question format such a noob here. i just have one last question is there any way to keep the console open would adding a Console.ReadKey at the end work?

Comment: As you said, just write Console.ReadKey() at the end. Mark as answer if this helped you to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `Console.Read` properly. `Console.Read` doesn't automatically store the user's input whenever they type into the console - you have to explicitly capture and store it if you want to use it.

If I were you, I'd use `Console.ReadLine()`, which takes all of the user's input up until they press enter.

To get the value of `multiply`, you could do something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Minutes: ");
int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Note that you need to do `int.Parse` on the user's input, as `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter 1 no.");
        float i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("enter 2 no.");
        float j = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (j % i == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("devide no.is {0}", j);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wrong input");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but it working is wrong it not not divide the numbers correctly and give the wrong input can any one  correct it